# Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

So i have Rails applications, i installed react-rails gem, set it up and try to run test application.

Freshly installed, when i tryed to run hello world program, this error hapened:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined

This is my react:

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <p>
        Hello, <input type="text" placeholder="Your name here" />!
        It is {this.props.date.toTimeString()}
      </p>
    );
  }
});

setInterval(function() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <HelloWorld date={new Date()} />,
    document.getElementById('example')
  );
}, 500);
```

Its saved inside /app/assets/javascripts/components/test.js.jsx file.

Rails 4.2.4 With Ruby 2.2.3

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`ReactDOM` available since version **0.14.0**, so you need to use `React.render` (because you have a React version **0.13.3**) instead,

```
setInterval(function() {
  React.render(
    <HelloWorld date={new Date()} />,
    document.getElementById('example')
  );
}, 500);
```

or upgrade your `React` version and include `ReactDOM`

> [Changes in React 0.14](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html)

Comment: That did the trick, i got another error, but i think i will just remove the gem and install newest react version manualy. Thanks for the response!!!

Answer (score 87):

It may be the spelling issue - it is `ReactDOM`, not `ReactDom`.

This has changed over time with the new release of React

Comment: Something strange is happening here.  I'm not sure that this should be correct based on the tutorial available (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) but my app actually started working when I changed ReactDom to ReactDOM when using 15.0.1 and ReactDom 15.0.1.

Comment: Unbelievable. Just spent an hour tearing my hair out making wrong assumptions as to why SystemJS (that's what I was using) was telling me ReactDom was undefined. Finally saw this answer, replaced the spelling to ReactDOM, and it works...Oh boy.

Comment: Perfect click boss!

Comment: Very common error. I've done this many times with ReactDOM. Watch out for it.

Answer (score 18):

You have to import it

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Answer (score 9):

Make sure that you've included `react-dom.js`. You can add it from CDN or use js toolchain of your choice.

[Installing React - using a CDN](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html#using-a-cdn)

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Make sure it's ReactDOM (case sensitive)
> ```

```
          class App extends React.Component {
            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <div className="commentbox">Hello React ! </div>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }
        ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work properly, you have to do 3 things.

1. Import the CDNs, necessary for the developement(Say react and react-dom for web development)

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

2. install `babel-cli` . It is needed for the compilation of JSX into vanila js
3. change the typo in your code,

it is `ReactDOM` , not RaactDOM